# Select an application among a number of applications using Python

Tags: python, automation

I am totally new to Python but I had a few success in solving small small problems. I am looking to know if the below is possible and, if so?

If I have, say, 10 different browser windows (not tabs), and if I need to select the browsers one by one, so that I can automatically click something in each of them is this attainable using Python?

Comment: When you mention browsers, do you just mean to interact with the pages contents? You can look into `python selenium` to interact with the websites and make use of `scrapy` for your pull/post requests.

Comment: The short answer is that there's no easy way to get python to interact directly with other _already-running_ programs that aren't made to be interoperable. However, [it's possible to get python to interact with the screen, mouse, and keyboard directly, and thus other running programs indirectly](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter18/). The problem with this is that you'd need to make sure the positioning and everything is perfect or else your script would desync.